# Is there any way through which I can show a listing of posts with a specific category on admin panel in WordPress Setup?

Tags: wordpress, blogs, posts

I have a WordPress website. For some reasons I want to show a listing of posts with a specific category separately on admin (dashboard) panel.

Is there any way?

Comment: There surely must be. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Go to all posts and simply type the category name within the searchbar.